# Click outside the mark (or point) to close something on Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

On my Mapbox have 3 layers.
`id: 'Map'`, `id:'Cluster'`, `id: 'Point'`

```
map.on('click', 'Point', function (e) {
    $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");/*show sidebar*/
  });
```

This code mean when I click point on layer `id: 'Point'`, sidebar will show.

```
$(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");/*hide sidebar*/
```

And this code will hide sidebar when add to event.

Now, I want click any where without point on layer `id: 'Point'` sidebar will hidden.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 10):

Use the click event handler for the entire map and the [`preventDefault`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#mapmouseevent#preventdefault) function:

```
  map.on('click', 'point', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('show sidebar');
  });

  map.on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.defaultPrevented === false) {
      console.log('hide taskbar');
    }
  });
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/7mfb59qo/2/ ]

Comment: A note for those who find this answer useful. This example only works when the events are mapped in this order: layered events first, whole-map events second. Otherwise, the defaultPrevented prop stays false as the layer event fires later